# Basic Python List Excercise

Tags: python

How do I make this graph print vertically rather than horizontally? Please try to use the same concept(loops, lists) I used in my code so I understand the changes. Thank you for your help!

**Here is the code:**

```
SIGN='x'

test_list=[500000,5000000,7000000]
test_calc_list=[]
test_sum=sum(test_list)

test_string_list=['Test1','Test2','Test3']
signs_list=[]

for x in test_list:
    test_calc=round((x/float(test_sum)*10))
    test_calc_list.append(test_calc)

for y in test_calc_list:
    y=int(y)
    signs=y*SIGN
    signs_list.append(signs)

for z in range(len(test_string_list)):
    print "%8s: %-6s %7i"% (test_string_list[z],signs_list[z],test_list[z])
```

**This is the output I get:**

```
Test1:           500000
Test2: xxxx     5000000
Test3: xxxxxx   7000000
```

**This is the output I want:**

```
                      x
           x          x
           x          x
           x          x
           x          x
Test1      Test2      Test3        
500000     5000000    7000000
```

Comment: This looks like homework, you will need to go about this in a very different way. start with finding the longest row of x's so you know how many lines you need to loop over, for each line check if their should be an x in the appropriate column if so print it, the bottom two rows I am sure you can manage

Comment: I agree that this looks like homework.  @Drake, can you tell us if this question is homework?  We will be happy to guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @chappy, the homework part was graphing it horizontally. Since I already got that down, I tried to make a vertical graph of the same information. So the question I am asking is not for homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this isn't homework (you do know that there is software to detect plagiarism?) here are possible solutions.

Easiest is to assume the list is a fixed size:

```
for i in range(len(max(signs_list)), 0, -1):
    print ('{0:<8} {1:<8} {2}').format(
        'x' if len(signs_list[0]) >= i else '', 
        'x' if len(signs_list[1]) >= i else '', 
        'x' if len(signs_list[2]) >= i else '')
print ('{0:<8} {1:<8} {2}').format(test_string_list[0], test_string_list[1], test_string_list[2])
print ('{0:<8} {1:<8} {2}').format(test_list[0], test_list[1], test_list[2])
```

Trickier is dealing with lists of arbitrary size which requires `eval`

```
for i in range(len(max(signs_list)), 0, -1):
    template_string = ""
    input_string = ""
    for z in range(len(test_string_list)):
        string_part = "{" + str(z) + ":<8} "
        template_string += string_part
        input_part = "'x' if len(signs_list[" \
            + str(z) + "]) >= i else '',"
        input_string += input_part
    statement = "('" + template_string + "')"
    statement += ".format"
    statement += "(" + input_string[:-1] + ")"
    print eval(statement)

template_string = ""
input_string = ""
for z in range(len(test_string_list)):
    string_part = "{" + str(z) + ":<8} "
    template_string += string_part
    input_part = "test_list[" + str(z) + "],"
    input_string += input_part
statement = "('" + template_string + "')"
statement += ".format"
statement += "(" + input_string[:-1] + ")"
print eval(statement)

template_string = ""
input_string = ""
for z in range(len(test_string_list)):
    string_part = "{" + str(z) + ":<8} "
    template_string += string_part
    input_part = "test_string_list[" + str(z) + "],"
    input_string += input_part
statement = "('" + template_string + "')"
statement += ".format"
statement += "(" + input_string[:-1] + ")"
print eval(statement)
```

The above monstrosity could can be refactored to remove the statement construction:

```
def statement_constructor(list_type, list_size):
    template_string = ""
    input_string = ""
    for z in range(list_size):
        string_part = "{" + str(z) + ":<8} "
        template_string += string_part
        if list_type == "signs_list":
            input_part = "'x' if len(signs_list[" \
                + str(z) + "]) >= i else '',"
        else:
            input_part = list_type + "[" + str(z) + "],"
        input_string += input_part
    statement = "('" + template_string + "')"
    statement += ".format"
    statement += "(" + input_string[:-1] + ")" 
    return statement

length = len(test_string_list)
for i in range(len(max(signs_list)), 0, -1):
    print eval(statement_constructor('signs_list', length))
print eval(statement_constructor('test_list', length))
print eval(statement_constructor('test_string_list', length))
```

All three produce the same output:

```
                  x        
                  x        
         x        x        
         x        x        
         x        x        
         x        x        
500000   5000000  7000000  
Test1    Test2    Test3
```

Although the solution using `eval` could handle Test4, Test5, and so on.  There may be a more elegant solution, but this works.

Edit:
Or the more elegant solution without `eval` overkill suggested in the comment by Michael0x2a.

```
def statement_constructor(list_type, list_size):
    template_string = ""
    input_string = ""
    array = []
    for z in range(list_size):
        string_part = "{:<8}"
        template_string += string_part
        if list_type == "signs_list":
            array.append('x' if len(signs_list[z]) >= i else '')
        elif list_type == 'test_list':
            array.append(test_list[z])
        else:
            array.append(test_string_list[z])
    print (template_string).format(*array)


length = len(test_string_list)
for i in range(len(max(signs_list)), 0, -1):
    statement_constructor('signs_list', length)
statement_constructor('test_list', length)
statement_constructor('test_string_list', length)
```

Comment: I think using `eval` is overkill here. Instead, you could iterate through the number of columns there are to create the `format` string (just append `'{:<8}'` to the format string per column (no need for the number)). Then, you iterate through the elements inside the `signs_list` and add the `'x'` or `''` strings to an array. Then, do `format_string.format(*array)`.